# How to properly read this captcha?

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I have the following code, which I am using to read a captcha, but there I cannot do it correctly:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

image = cv2.imread('simpleCaptcha - 2021-06-18T110955.962.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 10, 150)
canny = cv2.dilate(canny, None, iterations=1)

cv2.imshow('image',image) 
cv2.imshow('canny',canny)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Since despite the code it could not get close to the result I want. For the moment, this is the closest I have been to solving this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the color information here, e.g. by thresholding the saturation channel from the [HSV color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('crop.png')

# Threshold saturation channel from HSV color space using Otsu's method
s = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[..., 1]
s = cv2.threshold(s, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Blur mask to somehow connect lines, and merge characters' contours
s = cv2.GaussianBlur(s, (11, 11), sigmaX=0)

# Run pytesseract with page segmentation method 6
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(s, config='--psm 6')
print(text.replace('\n', '').replace('\f', ''))
# e6y2g
```

That's the cropped captcha from your screenshot:

[image: Cropped captcha]

That's the thresholded saturation channel:

[image: Thresholded saturation channel]

And, that's the mask after some Gaussian blurring:

[image: Mask after Gaussian blurring]

The blurring is done to somehow connect the lines, and to "merge" those double contours of the characters. You could do further processing, but Tesseract already properly detects the correct characters.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.2
OpenCV:        4.5.2
pytesseract:   5.0.0-alpha.20201127
----------------------------------------
```